# Weighted binary crossentropy in U-Net (Keras)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, loss, cross-entropy

I am currently working on a modified version on the U-Net (https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) and tried to implement a weighted binary crossentropy loss function in Keras.

```
    def weighted_pixelwise_crossentropy(self, wmap):

        def loss(y_true, y_pred):

             return losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * wmap

        return loss
```

Although this implementation works, I have failed to see any effect on the overall training, validation and prediction accuracy and am therefore wondering if this implementation is correct.

Could somebody tell me if the above weighted loss function is correctly implemented or if I made some mistake I have so far failed to recognize?

Comment: What do you want to weight? Samples? Pixels? Classes?

Comment: The weights are corresponding to image arrays, in which background pixels are given lower weights than foreground pixels, while additionally giving higher weights to foreground objects in close proximity to each other.

Comment: You mean `wmap` has the same shape as `y_true`? (What about batch size?)